# How to send array map data to database as STRING?

Tags: javascript, android, database, reactjs, react-native

Good day, I'm trying to send some data to my database by using array map. I actually did it, but the thing is I have to send it as a **STRING** together.

What actually happens is when I send the data, it be like each **rows** in the database.

So, my actual goal is to send both at the same time at the same row.

[image]

Here's my code

```
            fetch('http://192.168.254.***:****/SendOrder/Send',
            {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    tbl_id: this.state.Checked_ORDER_NO,
                    .... // other data
                })
            }).then(res => res.json())
                .then((responseJson) => {
                    console.log(responseJson);
                })
            .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))

For_table_No() {
        return this.state.CHECKED_Data.map((item) => {
            return (
                <View>
                    <View key={key}>
                        <Text>Merged Table: { item.Checked }</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
            )
        })
}

render() {
     return{
           ....
               { this.For_table_No() }
           ....
     }
}
```

ScreenShot:

UI:

[image]

Database:

[image]

Comment: I'm confused: you say you're trying to send data to your database. That sounds like an insert/update type database operation. And you mention `map`, but the only `map` statement that I see is part of your react rendering, which would be the opposite: reading data *out* of the database and displaying it.

Comment: Your question is confusing.. you want the output to have both these rows separated by a single comma and in a single row.. is that what you are expecting ?

Comment: @gopigorantala no sir, what i'm trying to say is send the 10 and 7 to be in the same row.

Answer (score 0):

Try tis code:

```
state = {
    data: ''
}

yourfunc = () => {
    fetch('your url', {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            //other headers
        }
    })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(result => {
            result.data.forEach(item => {
                let olddata = this.state.data
                this.setState(prevState => ({
                    data: `${item.id}, ${olddata}`
                }))
            })
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
}

render() {

    return (

        <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            <Text>{this.state.data}</Text>
        </View>

    )
}
```

you can customize with your own logic, hope this help :)

**Edited:**

Wait, sorry I don't get the real question is, I thougth you want to show the data in a rows.